# How do I generate a grid with a list of lists with labels

Tags: math, wolfram-mathematica

I have a list of lists like {{1,3,c1},{2,3,c2},{66,4,c3}…} and I’d like to make a grid with the first row being the first element in the lists, the first column being the second element, and then the elements *c* are located under their corresponding first and second elements. Is there any way to do this in mathematica?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do this. I give only a classic example.

The `SparseArray` function can read a specification of this kind and convert it

```
tt={{1,3,c1},{2,3,c2},{7,4,c3}};

qq= SparseArray[Map[Most[#]->Last[#]&,tt]]

TableForm[qq, TableHeadings->{Range[Length[qq]],Range[Length[Transpose@qq]]}]
```

[image: Table produced]

If you want to use something different than integers as indices,
this is also possible but requires a kind of translation.

If you need to have a sparse display of the sparse array you display
it requires a light pre-treatment before one use Mathematica commands such
as Tableform or Grid.

Answer (score 0):

```
xss = {{1, 3, c1}, {2, 3, c2}, {10, 4, c3}}
toGrid[xss_] := xss // Map[Most@# -> Last@# &] // SparseArray[#] & // Grid
toGrid@xss
```

[image]